# How to debug JBossESB?

Tags: java, xml, debugging, jboss-esb

Many times when I use JBossESB something does not work, because of configuration issues. In complex ESB its not obvious what is wrong. I do know I can use tracing with system.out's, but is there any way to use debug to detect those configuration errors?

I do not have any experience with debugging JBoss Server or JBoss ESB code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best thing to do is use small service configurations and make liberal use of org.jboss.soa.esb.actions.SystemPrintln.

It's also possible to attach the source to a tool like JBDS (or Eclipse, or Netbeans, etc.) and debug that way.